# Error while copying file on remote server with server path

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to copy upload files to remote server i get below exception.
It takes 5 min to copy a 100kb file.

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.CreateFile(String lpFileName, Int32 dwDesiredAccess, FileShare dwShareMode, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttrs, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, Int32 dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile)
   at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.SafeCreateFile(String lpFileName, Int32 dwDesiredAccess, FileShare dwShareMode, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttrs, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, Int32 dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.Net.Mail.AttachmentBase.SetContentFromFile(String fileName, String mediaType)
   at System.Net.Mail.Attachment..ctor(String fileName)
   at AFI.WarrantyClaim.SendConfirmationMail(String sClaimID, String sRecepient, Boolean bIsCust, ArrayList alUploadedFiles)
   at AFI.WarrantyClaim.btnNext_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Code which is causing this issue :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Request.Files.Count - 1
            Dim hpfFile As HttpPostedFile = Request.Files(i)

            If hpfFile.ContentLength > 0 Then
                Dim sFileExtention As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(hpfFile.FileName)
                Dim sFileName As String = String.Empty

                sFileName = sClaimNo + "_" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(hpfFile.FileName) + "_" + iPhoto.ToString() + _
                            sFileExtention

                Dim sScopeIdentity As String = SaveImageData(Convert.ToInt32(sClaimNo), Convert.ToString(iPhoto), sFileName)
                hpfFile.SaveAs(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(m_sUPLOADED_FILE_PATH) + sFileName)


               iPhoto = iPhoto + 1
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the operation is getting Timed Out .... check for the firewall settings on your PC, or check the log on the remote server.

Comment: hpfFile.SaveAs(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(m_sUPLOADED_FILE_PATH) + sFileName) : This like is causing. I checked access for remote server and found access is exist. But it takes so much time to copy small file. Can you please explain in detail

Comment: in case of a remote server ... check out how much time is used in 1. resolving host, 2. saving the file. u can put some kind of timer in between(before and after save as) ... and check firewall log (runtime) ans see where the time is wasted .... i think that the host resolving is taking time, or the bandwidth is very low